# Wordpress plugins are not working

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I created a wordpress theme.But plugins are not working in my theme.
Is there any function to be registered in order to work plugins?

Answer (score 0):

every theme should have a call to `wp_head()` somewhere in the  section of the output page. This allows a plugin to "hook" into your ```, and for example, output code to load its Javascript

Comment: I pasted  <?php wp_head(); ?> in header.php. Still the pblm exist :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have properly installed plugins foremost work is to activate them.

If you have not activated your plugin then go Plugins=>Installed Plugins

There you will find all the plugins you have installed and you can Activate from there, from the ACTIVATE link under the Plugins' name.

In case you have installed and activated the plugins. Then you need you need to use its shortcode on pages to use it.
In case you want to use it in some php file of your theme then you need to place its "php" code at proper place in order to get its result.

Hope you get it how we use Plugins in wordpress.

Comment: the plugin you are trying to use is compatible with your existing wordpress setup?

Comment: In case you have created your on full fledge theme then please check http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/9-common-wordpress-problems-and-how-to-solve-them/ to check what problem you are facing the problem to it

Answer (score 0):

Also wp_footer() is required on the footer before the end tag of  to load required javascript files you enqueued. 
Did you make your plugin header right?
Take a look here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header